# Implement SelectField for Material-UI v1.0.0-alpha.21 - Menu anchorEl issue

Tags: javascript, material-ui

Since Material-UI v1.0.0 hasn't implemented yet the selectField I'm trying to implement my own using TextField, Menu and MenuItem Components.

This is my code:

```
export default class SelectField extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            anchorEl: undefined,
            open: false,
        };
    }
    
    handleClick = event => {
        this.setState({ open: true, anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
    };

    handleRequestClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };
    
    handleMenuItemClick = (event, index) => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
        this.props.onChange(index);
    };
    
    render(){
        const { style, name, label, value, onChange, children } = this.props;
        
        return (
            <div>
            <TextField style={style} onClick={this.handleClick} type="text" name={name} label={label} value={value} InputProps={{ placeholder: label }} />
                <Menu open={this.state.open} anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl} onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose} >
                    {children.map((key) =>
                        <MenuItem key={key.value} selected={key.value === this.props.value} onClick={event => this.handleMenuItemClick(event, key.  value)} >
                            {key.name}
                        </MenuItem>,
                    )}
                </Menu>
            </div>          
        );
    }
}
```

Now my first problem comes when I try to positioning the Menu. At Material-UI docs I saw they used the property anchorEl to do put the menu in front of the element that is opening it. Ok, that works fine until you use selected property with lots of items. And I also want to ajust the position of the menu to be downside the TextField.

Also but not that much important. I want to set the width of the menu to the width of the TextField and also I want to allow search by writing o the Menu.

Comment: I found what's happening is a bug, someone fixed it several hours ago I just have to wait for the npm package to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem about the positioning of the menu yesterday. After checking out the source code of the [Menu.js](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Menu/Menu.js), I found that the Menu Component is wrapped by the internal Popover Component. So you could pass **anchorOrigin** prop to the Menu Component realizing customized positioning. But in my tests, it could only receive the anchorOrigin prop. There will be an error when you pass the targetOrigin prop, so I am trying to figure it out.